# Join items of an array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
const words = ['a man', 'a man who', "hiding"];

const speechWords = ["this", "is", "a", "man", "hiding", "under", "blanket", "a", "man", "who", "lives", "here"];
```

And I want to search if there are matching items (matching orders of the words) from `words` array inside `speechWords` and return a new array like this:

```
["this", "is", "a man", "hiding", "under", "blanket", "a man who", "lives", "here"]
```

Note that if we have a matching phrase from `words` we should join the matches of `speechWords`.

**Note:**  the order of `speechWords` should not be changed.

I tried to loop through `words` array split the words and search each one from another for loop over `speechWords` with no luck...

Answer (score 2):

One option is to replace spaces in the big string with some symbol and then insert substrings from the `words` array:

```js
const words = ['a man', 'a man who', "hiding"];

const speechWords = ["this", "is", "a", "man", "hiding", "under", "blanket", "a", "man", "who", "lives", "here"];

s = speechWords.join('@')
for (sub of words)
    s = s.replace(sub.replaceAll(' ', '@'), sub)
s = s.split('@')

console.log(s)
```

Comment: Quick note, if you want to be safer against the symbol clashing with existing symbols, you can use something like the UTF unit separator `"\u241F"` which makes the clashes with text extremely unlikely. But that's rarely needed, a symbol like `@` or `^` might be enough in most cases.

Comment: Thanks plus one but this is not what I'm looking for const words = ['a man', 'a man w']; gives us the same result .

Comment: @SaraRee: this can be remedied with something like `new RegExp('\\b' + sub.replaceAll(' ', '@') + '\\b')`

Answer (score -2):

For copying an arry

const arr = [1,2,4,6]

const data = [...arr,7,9,12]

console.log(data)
//[1, 2,  4, 6, 7, 9, 12 ]